# sorting English Words before Chinese words in SQLite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sorting, collation

I have a table 'Phone_Contact' which has column ContactsId, DevId, FName, FNamePinYinSpel . FName will have both Chinese and English conatct names. Now as per requirement I could manage to get the contacts in below order :

```
FName            FNamePinYinSpel
北蔡王先生        Bei Cai Wang Xian Shen
广州房东          Fang Hua Lu Qi Tian Lian Suo
jie王             Jie wang
杰wang            Jie wang
Lastname Tess     Lastname Tess
李 二             Li er
李 四             Li si
李 一             Li yi
李 一 一          Li yi yi
林 二             Lin er
林 一             Lin yi
林 一 一          Lin yi yi
凌 一             Ling yi
凌 一 一          Ling yi yi
凌 二             Ling er
凌 依依           Ling yi yi
```

by using below query

```
SELECT icu_load_collation('en-u-ks-level1-kr-latn-zh','PinyinM')";

SELECT FName from Phone_Contact where DevId is 1 ORDER BY substr(FNamePinYinSpel ,1,5), (substr(FName,1,5) < 'zz'), FName COLLATE PinyinM LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0 ;
```

But the desired is mentioned below.

```
FName              FNamePinYinSpel
北蔡王先生          Bei cai wang xian shen
广州房东            Fang hua lu qi tian lian suo
jie王              Jie wang
杰wang             Jie wang
Lastname Tess      Lastname Tess
李 二              Li er
李 四              Li si
李 一              Li yi
李 一 一           Li yi yi
林 二              Lin er
林 一              Lin yi
林 一 一           Lin yi yi
凌 二              Ling er
凌 一              Ling yi
凌 一 一           Ling yi yi
凌 依依            Ling yi yi
```

Can anyone help me to get the desired output
Note: FNamePinYinSpel is English equivalent of Chinese names.

Comment: Sample rows and desired order, in the body of your question as text, not an image, would be useful.

Comment: converted from image to text for better readability,

Comment: You have Li Yi Yi twice in the first list but once in the second list?

Comment: sorry for the Typo. i have updated the table.

Comment: For anyone else is reading, the only difference between two result sets is only for "Ling er" changing its position.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ORDER BY` clause is not doing what you are intending to do. It is considering only the first 5 characters of `FNamePinYinSpel`.

```
ORDER BY substr(FNamePinYinSpel ,1,5), (substr(FName,1,5) < 'zz')
```

But it appears you want to sort by the whole `FNamePinYinSpel`. In that case, just remove 5 character limitations and there is no need to include `(substr(FName,1,5) < 'zz')` part. That could be useful if both Chinese names and English name were mixed up in a single column but you have `FNamePinYinSpel` which has all English names

```
ORDER BY FNamePinYinSpel
```

Comment: I'm trying to sort many languages, @K4M can sort Englist before chine with rules SELECT icu_load_collation('en-u-ks-level1-kr-latn-zh','PinyinM'); I have a question about what code of icu_load_collation if Chinese before English?